# Tensorflow access elements in tensor using tenors on indices

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, indexing

How can I access tenor elements in tensorflow `Tensor` using tensor indices as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# indexing in numpy [Working]
matrix = np.random.randint(0, 10, [100, 100])
indices = np.random.randint(0, 100, [1000, 100])
elements = matrix[indices[:, 0], indices[:, 1]]

# indexing in tensorflow [Not working]
tf_matrix = tf.constant(matrix, dtype=tf.int32)
tf_indices = tf.constant(indices, dtype=tf.int32)
tf_elements = tf_matrix[tf_indices[:, 0], tf_indices[:, 1]]  # Error

session = tf.Session()
session.run(tf_elements)
```

I get these errors:

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Shape
>   must be rank 1 but is rank 2 for 'strided_slice_2' (op:
>   'StridedSlice') with input shapes: [100,100], [2,1000], [2,1000], [2].
>
> ValueError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 2 for 'strided_slice_2'
>   (op: 'StridedSlice') with input shapes: [100,100], [2,1000], [2,1000],
>   [2].

Answer (score 1):

```
tf_elements = tf.gather_nd(tf_matrix, tf_indices[:, 0:2])
```